# How to enable disable text input while making my function modular

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here is my script, what my goal is if other is selected in select, the other text input beside it will be enabled, this is what i've got so far, any approach will be really appreciated, I have 4 questions like this and I want it to be modular, best approach for doing my function to be reuseable.. How do I properly do this without any problem posting my data as 2 name inputs will generate 2 post variables in php.. T_T

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function validate()
    {
     var ddl = document.getElementById("cause_pain");
     var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
        if (selectedValue == "OTHER")
       {
        document.getElementsByClassName("causepain")[0].removeAttribute("name");
        document.getElementsByClassName("causepain1")[0].removeAttribute("disabled");
       }
    }
</script>

<form action="test.php" method="GET">

                                        <select class="select causepain" id="cause_pain" name="cause_pain" onchange="validate()">
                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select Cause of Pain</option>
                                        <option value="ARTHRITIS">ARTHRITIS</option>
                                        <option value="RHEUMATISM">RHEUMATISM</option>
                                        <option value="OLD AGE">OLD AGE</option>
                                        <option value="ACTIVE LIFESTYLE WHEN YOUNGER">ACTIVE LIFESTYLE WHEN YOUNGER</option>        
                                        <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                        </select>   
                                        <input class="causepain1" type="text" id="cause_pain" name="cause_pain" size="40" onkeyup="clean('this.id')" disabled>
<input type="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is reusable and pretty straight forward. Using data attributes, you could specify the element that needs to be shown on the specific option element. Also before showing any input element hide the elements that were attributed to the previous selection.

**Example:**

```
    <form action="test.php" method="GET">
        <select class="select causepain" id="cause_pain" name="cause_pain">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select Cause of Pain</option>
            <option value="ARTHRITIS">ARTHRITIS</option>
            <option value="RHEUMATISM">RHEUMATISM</option>
            <option value="OLD AGE">OLD AGE</option>
            <option value="ACTIVE LIFESTYLE WHEN YOUNGER">ACTIVE LIFESTYLE WHEN YOUNGER</option>
            <option value="OTHER" data-show="cause_pain_other">OTHER</option>
        </select>
        <input class="causepain1" type="text" id="cause_pain_other" name="cause_pain" size="40"
               onkeyup="clean('this.id')" disabled style="display: none;">
        <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var selectedOpt;
        function selectionChanged(e) {
            if (selectedOpt && selectedOpt.dataset.show) {
                var showEl = document.getElementById(selectedOpt.dataset.show);
                showEl.disabled = true;
                showEl.style.display = 'none';
            }
            selectedOpt = this.querySelector('[value="'+e.target.value+'"]');
            if (selectedOpt.dataset.show) {
                var showEl = document.getElementById(selectedOpt.dataset.show);
                showEl.disabled = false;
                showEl.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
        document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', selectionChanged);
    </script>
```

Your `selectedOpt` should be an object if you're using multiple selects on the same page and then just add the element to the object with the id as an index:

```
var selectedOpt = {};
...
selectedOpt[this.id] = this.querySelector('[value="'+e.target.value+'"]');
```